# Chrome Extension - make a full page screenshot - TypeError: chrome.tabs.captureTab is not a function

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to capture a full page screenshot of a web page through a chrome extension. I have managed to capture a screenshot with chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab but I'd like to capture the full page.

I have tried chrome.tabs.captureTab but I always end up with the same error message:
TypeError: chrome.tabs.captureTab is not a function

Here is the code:

```
async function createTab (url) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        chrome.tabs.create({url}, tab => resolve(tab));
    });
}


(async() => {
    let tab = await createTab('https://www.laurentwillen.be');
    chrome.tabs.captureTab(tab.id, { format: "png" }, function(image) {
         chrome.downloads.download({
            url: image,
            filename: "screenshot.png",
            saveAs: false
        });
    });

})();
```

I'm using Chrome 108 under Windows. Is the chrome.tabs.captureTab supported by this version ?

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: See this. [tabs​.captureTab()](https://contest-server.cs.uchicago.edu/ref/JavaScript/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureTab.html)

Comment: @NorioYamamoto Thanks but from what I see it only captures the visible part, I'm looking for a solution to capture the whole page.

Comment: The page I referred to says that `chrome.tabs.captureTab` is not supported in Chrome.

Comment: There's no such function in Chrome. Use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you know any alternative to capture the full screen? I thought of scrolling down the screen and take other shots but each time I do this, it still captures the top of the page. Thanks